# Zebra GK420d label printer - status reporting

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, epl

I am trying to understand how I can sent status requests to these label printers to see if they are free to print labels.

The problem I have is that if I send too many label print requests then only some of get printed. I think the problem is that the memory buffer of the printer is getting overwritten and some of the labels are being deleted and not printed.

I have tried to ~HS command but can't figure out what parameter I need to check as the documentation is not very good.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `bufferFullFlag` will tell you if the printer's buffer is full and cannot receive any more print jobs. You can query that (it's the 6th parameter).  You should also look at the `paperOutFlag` and `pauseFlag` to make sure the printer is ready to print.

If you use the [Zebra SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html), you can call the `ZebraPrinter.getCurrentStatus()` and that will return a class that contains the `~HS` parameters as primitive data types so that you don't have to parse it yourself. There is also a combo boolean called `isReadyToPrint` which looks at several of the status bits to see if you can send a job to the printer